(COMPLETED) Site maintenance - Thursday, May 16th, 2024, 22:00 - 23:00 UTC (6 PM - 7 PM EDT)
[UPDATE - Maintenance complete]
We will be performing maintenance on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites on Thursday, May 16th, 2024, 22:00 - 23:00 UTC (6 PM - 7 PM EDT).
During the maintenance window, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange members using our deprecated OpenID login flow may be unable to login for brief periods, lasting no more than a few minutes each. Members logging in with Google, Facebook, GitHub, etc. will not be affected. We'll update this post when the maintenance has been completed. Thank you for your understanding.

"Members logging in with Google, FB, GitHub, etc." - is the login with Stack Exchange email/password part of the "etc"? Or will it also be affected?

You could add the status completed tag, or is there some reason not to do that?

@CPlus no. Vast majority of the past cases were not marked with that tag, and there is really no reason to do that. It's not a bug, and not a feature request.

I thought the OpenID login flow was fully removed in 2018: you're saying it still works somewhere?

@wizzwizz4 I doubt we'll get answer here, better ask that as a new question.
